# how can i extract the quality of the video with vlc?

Tags: tkinter, vlc

i'm wondering if we

1- Recover the quality of the video that VLC is launching (not the resolution of the widget but quality video)

2 - If we can change it ?!

3- Recover the differents languages available of the video and change it ?

thanks a lot :)
my code for information (just need to change the path if you want to test it, basic vlc reader):

```
from tkinter import *
import vlc
#pyinstaller --onefile "c:/Users/Nicolas/Desktop/Python/Debut du code.py"
global text
import datetime
import time
from random import *

player = vlc.MediaPlayer("G:/Films/21 Jump Street.mkv")
player.play()#Lecture du fichier
player.toggle_fullscreen()#Plein écran

def Lancement():#affichage du controle dees boutons
    global Texte
    value = player.get_time() * 0.001  
    Fenetre.geometry('600x25+0+1055')#Positon de la fenetre et dimmensions
    Fenetre.overrideredirect(1) #Retire les bordures
    ok = Button(Fenetre, text="Retour", command=retour)#Bouton ok avec fonction ok
    ok.grid(row=0, column=0)#positon du bouton ave un grillage caché
    Lancer = Button(Fenetre, text="Pause", command=play)
    Lancer.grid(row=0, column=1)
    Temps = Button(Fenetre, text="Avancer", command=avancement)
    Temps.grid(row=0, column=3)
    Temps = Button(Fenetre, text="Reculer", command=reculervideo)
    Temps.grid(row=0, column=2)
    Texte=Label(Fenetre,text=value)#texte contenant le temps en cours
    Texte.grid(row=0, column=4)
    Fenetre.attributes("-topmost", True)#Mise en premier plan du bouton
    
def avancement():
    global temporaire    
    secondesvideos = player.get_length()* 0.001 #Duréée de la vidéo en secondes
    tempssecondesvideo = player.get_time() * 0.001  
    pourcentageactuel= (tempssecondesvideo*100//secondesvideos)
    pourcentage=(pourcentageactuel*0.01)
    player.set_position(pourcentage+0.01)
    
def reculervideo():
    global temporaire    
    secondesvideos = player.get_length()* 0.001 #Duréée de la vidéo en secondes
    tempssecondesvideo = player.get_time() * 0.001  
    pourcentageactuel= (tempssecondesvideo*100//secondesvideos)
    pourcentage=(pourcentageactuel*0.01)
    player.set_position(pourcentage-0.01)
        
def play():
    player.pause()#commande play de VLC
    
def retour():
    player.stop()#fermeture de vlc 
    Fenetre.destroy()#fermeture du controle pannel
    
#Bouton claviers-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def BoutonPause(event):
    if event.char == 'space':
        print(event.char)
        player.pause()#commande play de VLC

def Boutonavancer(event):
    if event.char == 'a':
        avancement()
 
def Boutonreculer(event):
    if event.char == 'r':
        reculervideo()    

def Boutonretour(event):
    if event.char == 'v':
        retour()   
    
def actualisation():
    global Texte#varaiable commun aux deux fonctions    
    DureeVideo = player.get_length()* 0.001 #Duréée de la vidéo en secondes
    DureeVideo = time.gmtime(DureeVideo)#converturisseur en H M S
    DureeVideo = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",DureeVideo)
    TempsActuel = player.get_time() * 0.001
    TempsActuel = time.gmtime(TempsActuel)
    TempsActuel = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",TempsActuel)
    TexteTemps=(TempsActuel,"/",DureeVideo)#stockage du texte dans la variable
    Texte.configure(text=TexteTemps)    #ecriture du texte dans le vlc    
    Fenetre.after(500, actualisation) # actualizsation toutes les seoncdes (ms)
    
    
   
Fenetre = Tk()#lancement des focntions
Fenetre.bind('<space>', BoutonPause)
Fenetre.bind('<a>', Boutonavancer)
Fenetre.bind('<r>', Boutonreculer)
Fenetre.bind('<v>', Boutonretour)

Lancement()
actualisation() 

Fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1. Define `quality`, what specific attribute of the video file do you wish to access? 2. Get languages - `player.video_get_track_description()` but only after it has started playing. 3. Change languages, I assume you mean select, `player.video_set_track(Lang_id)`

Comment: thank you ! very usefull !it works but it is right for the actual resolution of the video: :resolution = player.video_get_size(num=0) it gives return me :(1920, 816) but it's my screen resolution or the video resolution ? :)

Comment: I believe it's the currently displayed size i.e. the size of the window you are viewing the video in.

Comment: `libvlc_media_get_codec_description` is one of 39 function(s) not wrapped as methods (see vlc.py) for codec information use an external call to `ffprobe` instead.